# ROADM and OXC and their differences

Tags: optical

What is the relation between Reconfigurable Optical Add/Drop Multiplexer and Optical Cross-Connect? Are they two different things technically? or they are two concepts which have many things in common?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An *optical cross-connect* is a more general term for an optical switching device. The switching can be done electronically, purely optically, or mixed.

An *optical add-drop multiplexer* is a more specific device for wavelength-division multiplexing (WDM) that can merge and split off specific wavelengths/colors. With a *reconfigurable* OADM that behavior can be remotely controlled.